# Is it possible to bind to properties on a Component

Tags: winforms, binding

I have a component defined as:

```
public class MyComponent: Component
{
    //constructor, diposal etc omitted for brevity

    public bool MyBool {get; set;}
}
```

How can I bind to the MyBool property? Is this actually possible for something that implements `System.ComponentModel.Component`, or does it have to extend `System.Windows.Forms.Control`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the answer by my own research, it seems amazing to me that it was so hard to find an answer to this question once I found how to do it:

A `Component` lacks the required properties to manage bindings. To make a `Component` bindable in the Visual Studio designer, you must implement the `IBindableComponent` interface.

For example:

```
public abstract class MyComponent : Component, IBindableComponent
{
    private BindingContext bindingContext;
    private ControlBindingsCollection dataBindings;

    [Category("Data")]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public ControlBindingsCollection DataBindings
    {
        get { return dataBindings ?? (dataBindings = new ControlBindingsCollection(this)); }
    }

    [Browsable(false)]
    public BindingContext BindingContext
    {
        get { return bindingContext ?? (bindingContext = new BindingContext()); }
        set { bindingContext = value; }
    }
}
```

Note: The `DataBindings` property needs to be marked with `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]` otherwise bindings added in the designer will not be serialized